# LOS SCRIPTS DE R NO ABREN

Tags: script, rstudio

estaba intentando instalar el paquete caret en R y me pedía actualización. Realicé la actualización, luego instalé el paquete y pude correr los códigos. Sin embargo cuando fui a abrir mis otros script aparecen absolutamente todos en blanco. No tengo idea de que fue lo que sucedió y tampoco como hacer para que abran [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Abre el file luego ve a File->open with encoding y selecciona una de las opciones (UTF-8).

Slds!

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/393170)